# Restrict compose modifier that only accessible from my composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-modifier

I have a composable function:

```
@Composable
fun GapText(
    modifier: Modifier,
    text: String,
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier) {
        Text(text = text)
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a modifier that only **GapText** can use:

```
fun Modifier.customTag(tag: String) =
    this then CustomTag(tag)
```

But with this function that I wrote every composable function can use it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As of now there's no specific modifier for this, but what one could do is:

1 - Declare the Composable on a separated file and make the modifier private:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun GapText(
    modifier: Modifier,
    text: String,
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier) {
        Text(text = text)
        ...
    }
}

private fun Modifier.customTag(tag: String) =
    this then CustomTag(tag)
```

2 - Declare the modifier function within the Composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun GapText(
    modifier: Modifier,
    text: String,
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier) {
        Text(text = text)
        ...
    }

    fun Modifier.customTag(tag: String) =
        this then CustomTag(tag)
}
```

Comment: I don't know how these two approaches can help. in these two approaches no one cannot use the modifier on GapText fun:
'''
GapText(
    modifier = Modifier.customTag("tag")
    ....
)
'''